# Need particular folder level access in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am creating a user test in AWS IAM access . Also create a bucket name AWS-test,Under this bucket there is a folder called 'newfol' . I want to give permission to test user to particular newfol folder . test user only can upload file in newfol folder and also that user not able to see any other bucket or any other folder which is present under AWS-test .

I am written below json for that . But using that I able to enter AWS-test bucket and check all folder over there and upload file in all folder under AWs-test .

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AWS-test"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AWS-test/newfol/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your json will get a list of all objects in the AWS-test bucket. If you just want them to be able to upload to the newfol folder, then delete the first part of the json and it should work.

Comment: I also want to see all object which I upload in newfol  only .  How it's possible ?